# Absolute CSS text sizes not respected for small displays, even with text-size-adjust: none

Tags: html, css

To better characterize my vision difficulties, I've made a web page:

https://marknahabedian.github.io/VisionTests/words-test.html

It displays a series of randomly chosen words at progressively smaller font sizes.

One can choose a light or dark theme, and from several type faces and stroke weights to see if that helps.

I use the HTML `style` attribute with the absolute `pt` unit to conrol the text size.

When I look at this page on a small display like a smart phone
though, the text which has been given an absolute size in points
is much smaller than on my laptop, where 36pt text is half an
inch high.  I don't understand why the absolute size isn't
respected on small displays.

I include `text-size-adjust: none` and its browser specific
variants in my style rules but still on my phone the 36pt text is
only 1/4 inch tall.

Code is on GitHub:
https://github.com/MarkNahabedian/VisionTests

Example (without dynamic word list):

```js
WORD_LIST = ["cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act"];

// Size in points (CSS pt):
TEXT_SIZES = [ 
  36, 
  30, 
  24, 
  16, 
  14, 
  12, 
  10, 
  8, 
  6,
];
WORDS_PER_SIZE = 20;

window.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  (event) => {
      add_control_change_handlers();
      //load_word_list("2000_words.txt").then(initialize_words, console.log);
      initialize_words(WORD_LIST);
      select_theme();
      update_text();
  });

function add_control_change_handlers() {
    document.querySelector("#theme").addEventListener("change", select_theme);
    document.querySelector("#font-family").addEventListener("change", select_font_family);
    document.querySelector("#font-weight").addEventListener("change", select_font_weight);
}

function select_theme(event) {
    // Change class attribute of body element
    let body = document.querySelector("html > body");
    body.setAttribute("class",
    document.querySelector("#theme").value);
}

function select_font_family(event) {
    update_text();
}

function select_font_weight(event) {
    update_text();
}


function update_text() {
    // Update the style attribute of the #text element based on the
    // falues of the selected font family and weight.
    let text = document.getElementById("text");
    let family = document.querySelector("#font-family").value;
    let weignt = document.querySelector("#font-weight").value;
    text.setAttribute("style",
                      "font-family: " + family + "; " +
                      "font-weight: " + weignt + ";");
}

// Size in points (CSS pt):
TEXT_SIZES = [ 36, 30, 24, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6 ];
WORDS_PER_SIZE = 20;

// Using pt, text on my cell phone is half as high as expected -- 36pt
// is only 1/4" high.
// Using px, as sugfgested in
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496769/absolute-css-text-sizes-not-respected-for-small-displays-even-with-text-size-ad
// doesn't seem to fix the problem though.
function pt2px(pt) {
    return 96 * pt / 72;
}

function initialize_words(word_list) {
    let wordcount = word_list.length;
    text_elt = document.getElementById("text");
    for (let j = 0; j < TEXT_SIZES.length; j++) {
        let size_elt = document.createElementNS(text_elt.namespaceURI, "p");
        size_elt.setAttribute("style",
                              "font-size: " +
                              TEXT_SIZES[j] + "px;");
        size_elt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("" + TEXT_SIZES[j] + " "));
        for (let i = 0; i < WORDS_PER_SIZE; i++) {
            let word = word_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordcount)];
            let textnode = document.createTextNode(word + " ");
            size_elt.appendChild(textnode);
        }
        text_elt.appendChild(size_elt);
    }
}
```

```css
.controls
{
    display: block;
    font-size: large;
}

(html,body) *
{
    text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
}

body
{
    width: 90%;
}

.text
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.theme-dark
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;

}

.theme-light
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Vision Word Reading Test</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Vision Word Reading Test</h1>
    
    <div class="controls">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="theme">theme</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="theme">
              <option value="theme-dark">dark</option>
              <option value="theme-light">light</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <td>
          <label for="font-family">font family</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="font-family">
            <option value="monospace">monospace</option>
            <option value="ui-monospace">ui-monospace</option>
            <option value="sans-serif">sans-serif</option>
            <option value="ui-sans-serif">ui-sans-serif</option>
            <option value="serif">serif</option>
            <option value="ui-serif">ui-serif</option>
            <option value="system-ui">system-ui</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="font-weight">font weight</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="font-weight">
              <option value="normal">normal</option>
              <option value="bolder">bolder</option>
              <option value="lighter">lighter</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    <div id="text" class="text">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

I welcome your suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is probably that you are using pt (dot), which is ONLY used in printing. On the screen you use px (pixel) instead. I could well imagine that smartphones have a higher resolution and that's why the pt value gives such unexpected results because it is calculated smaller on the smartphone.

Comment: Thanks for responding.

I don't know what browsers implement, but a point is defined to be 1/72 inch.

My assumption is that the size of a pixel varies depending on screen resolution, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units says `1px = 1/96th of 1in`.

That doesn't account for a factor of 2 in size though.

Using px instead of pt, text on my phone is stilll only about half the size as on my laptop.

Comment: I can definitely tell you that measurements like pt or inch should not be used for web pages. for example, if you create a document in photoshop that is 5 inches wide and view it at 100%, it will only show you in 5 inch width if the resolution is the same your screen has. analog measurements are converted to digital with the resolution. if you create a document that is 500 pixels wide, it will always be 500 pixels wide no matter what resolution you set.
i think the fonts are converted in the same way. because a smartphone has twice the resolution, the font looks half the sice of your desktop.

Comment: in order for the font to really be displayed in the same real size on each device, you have to use media queries that react to the resolution. if the font is 20 pixels big at 72dpi, it has to be 40pixels big at 146 dpi. then you should be able to hold a ruler to the screens and the font should be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment, you should use pixel sizes when displaying something on a pixel screen. If you want the text to be the same size on every device, you have to multiply the pixel value by the resolution. This applies to Retina resolution on Apple or HD resolution on other devices, or 4K for example.
I have built an example here.

You can never make it perfect, because the pixel sizes are different on different devices. But from my point of view this is the best solution for your problem.

Edit:
i just saw on my macbook that i forgot something. only if a device has small pixels, like smartphones with high resolution you should multiply the pixel-size with the dpi. you still have to do that in this code that.
I'll have to see if I can find a solution for that too.

```js
WORD_LIST = ["cat", "dog", "tac", "god", "act"];

// Size in points (CSS pt):
TEXT_SIZES = [ 
  36 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  30 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  24 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  16 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  14 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  12 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  10 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  8 * window.devicePixelRatio, 
  6 * window.devicePixelRatio 
];
WORDS_PER_SIZE = 20;

window.addEventListener(
  "DOMContentLoaded",
  (event) => {
      add_control_change_handlers();
      initialize_words(WORD_LIST);
      select_theme();
      update_text();
  });

  function add_control_change_handlers() {
      document.querySelector("#theme").addEventListener("change", select_theme);
      document.querySelector("#font-family").addEventListener("change", select_font_family);
      document.querySelector("#font-weight").addEventListener("change", select_font_weight);
  }

function select_theme(event) {
    // Change class attribute of body element
    let body = document.querySelector("html > body");
    body.setAttribute("class",
    document.querySelector("#theme").value);
}

function select_font_family(event) {
    update_text();
}

function select_font_weight(event) {
    update_text();
}


function update_text() {
    // Update the style attribute of the #text element based on the
    // falues of the selected font family and weight.
    let text = document.getElementById("text");
    let family = document.querySelector("#font-family").value;
    let weignt = document.querySelector("#font-weight").value;
    text.setAttribute("style",
                      "font-family: " + family + "; " +
                      "font-weight: " + weignt + ";");
}


// Using pt, text on my cell phone is half as high as expected -- 36pt
// is only 1/4" high.
// Using px, as sugfgested in
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496769/absolute-css-text-sizes-not-respected-for-small-displays-even-with-text-size-ad
// doesn't seem to fix the problem though.
function pt2px(pt) {
    return 96 * pt / 72;
}


function initialize_words(word_list) {
    let wordcount = word_list.length;
    text_elt = document.getElementById("text");
    for (let j = 0; j < TEXT_SIZES.length; j++) {
        let size_elt = document.createElementNS(text_elt.namespaceURI, "p");
        size_elt.setAttribute("style",
                              "font-size: " +
                              TEXT_SIZES[j] + "px;");
        size_elt.appendChild(document.createTextNode("" + TEXT_SIZES[j] + " "));
        for (let i = 0; i < WORDS_PER_SIZE; i++) {
            let word = word_list[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordcount)];
            let textnode = document.createTextNode(word + " ");
            size_elt.appendChild(textnode);
        }
        text_elt.appendChild(size_elt);
    }
}
```

```css
.controls
{
    display: block;
    font-size: large;
}

(html,body) *
{
    text-size-adjust: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: none;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
}

body
{
    width: 90%;
}

.text
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.theme-dark
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;

}

.theme-light
{
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Vision Word Reading Test</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Vision Word Reading Test</h1>
    
    <div class="controls">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="theme">theme</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="theme">
              <option value="theme-dark">dark</option>
              <option value="theme-light">light</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <td>
          <label for="font-family">font family</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select id="font-family">
            <option value="monospace">monospace</option>
            <option value="ui-monospace">ui-monospace</option>
            <option value="sans-serif">sans-serif</option>
            <option value="ui-sans-serif">ui-sans-serif</option>
            <option value="serif">serif</option>
            <option value="ui-serif">ui-serif</option>
            <option value="system-ui">system-ui</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="font-weight">font weight</label>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select id="font-weight">
              <option value="normal">normal</option>
              <option value="bolder">bolder</option>
              <option value="lighter">lighter</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    
    <div id="text" class="text">
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: rather than manipulating font-size to adapt a client resolution, just use `vh` (viewport height units) - it does resize fonts based on the availble height of the clients viewport, but in percent - not in "pixels". So, giving `font-size: 50vh` will make a font cover 50% of the displays height, no matter what size, dpi or resolution the user is on.

Comment: i understood that the size on the screens should be as physically equal as possible. fonts are displayed with pixel values, so you should adjust the font size to the size of the pixels. that's my idea.
if you use the screen width, the font is sometimes 5 inches high and sometimes 20 inches. i think that was not the goal.

and if you define the text size in pixel, it is the same pixel size everywhere. that would be the easiest, if thats the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Implementation of viewport will vary by device / manufacturer. It's best to stick with standard sizing to achieve best possible support across viewports.

```css
.xxs{font-size: xx-small;}
.xs{font-size: x-small;}
.s{font-size: small;}
.m{font-size: medium;}
.l{font-size: large;}
.xl{font-size: x-large;}
.xxl{font-size: xx-large;}
.xxxl{font-size: xxx-large;}
```

```html
<span class="xxs">Hellow World</span><br>
<span class="xs">Hellow World</span><br>
<span class="s">Hellow World</span><br>
<span class="m">Hellow World</span><br>
<span class="l">Hellow World</span><br>
<span class="xl">Hellow World</span><br>
<span class="xxl">Hellow World</span><br>
<span class="xxxl">Hellow World</span>
```